# How to create a complete `.war` file with pom.xml

Tags: maven, soap, war, pom.xml

I have a web service project (SOAP) implemented in Java, as a Maven project. I want to create a `.war` to deploy into a Tomcat.

To create the `.war`, I always used the Eclipse Juno interface (Right click -> Export -> WAR File). The Eclipse is configured with Tomcat 7 and Axis 1.5.6. Using this method I deploy the `.war` file created and everything is fine! The main page of the application looks like below:

[![Web Service main page][1]][1]

In this page, I can explore the services, methods and WSDL files. This is what I call **complete `.war` file.**

Now, I migrated my web service to Maven, in order to use it with Jenkins, to automate the deploys, tests, etc.

I tried for two full days create a `pom.xml` which will create the same `.war` file that was created with Eclipse, but I was not successful. When I deploy the `.war` created using the `pom.xml` on a Tomcat and access the `localhost:8080/SOAPExample/`, it shows *Error 404*. The Maven build of the `.war` and the Tomcat deploy was successful. I understood that the service page was not created, but the web service was deployed successfuly.

I used some of the tutorials available in the internet, like the below, but in all cases the `.war` created by Maven is incomplete:

http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-war-file-from-eclipse-using-maven-plugin-apache-maven-war-plugin-usage/

https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

It looks like I'm missing some dependency configuration into the `pom.xml`, or something like that. Here is my `pom.xml`. I also think it is missing some axis2 configuration.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>SOAPExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SOAPExample</name>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my project sctructure:

[[![Project Folder Structure]][2][2]]

There is no tutorial in the internet explaining how to configure a `pom.xml` to create a **complete** `.war` file. Could some good soul help me?

Comment: Remove the configuration for `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and keep the default layout. This means `src/main/java` java code. `src/main/webapp` Web parts...Not things like `WebContent`...

Comment: Hello Khmarbaise,  I was unable to edit the image of my own question, but the folder structure is already as you suggest. Just delete the  "<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>"  did not take effect. Any other idea?

Comment: Removed the configuration for maven-war-plugin warSourceDirectory...and try `mvn clean package` on plain command line...